# python aws boto - sns.publish does not support text with emoji

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

We're using AWS boto SNS publish to publish our push notifications.

```
pub_result = self.conn.publish(message=message_json,target_arn=device_arn,message_structure='json')
```

if the message text includes emoji, we get an exception:
line 490, in add_auth\n    qs = self.query_string(req)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/auth.py", line 332, in query_string\n    pval = str(http_request.params[pname]).encode(\'utf-8\')\nUnicodeDecodeError: \'ascii\' codec can\'t decode byte 0xf0 in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)\n', 'error': u"'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)"}

A possible solution is to change in:
https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/auth.py

line 333:
replace:

```
val = str(http_request.params[pname]).encode('utf-8')
```

with:

```
val = unicode(http_request.params[pname]).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: see proposal for solution

Comment: solved in boto 2.27.0

Released: 6-March-2014 https://github.com/boto/boto